# C# Cannot implicitly convert one form to another form

Tags: c#, forms

So i am trying to store my main form and open a new one however i get this error, here is the code:

I have this at form level

```
public static frmAddBook frmkeepBooks = null;

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frmkeepBooks = this;
}
```

The error underlines "this" saying it "`Cannot inplicitly convert type Books.frmMain to Books.frmAddBook`"

Comment: yes, because both the classes doesn't have any relation

Comment: `this` represents the `Books.frmMain`. Indeed it cannot be converted to a `frmAddBook` object. You're trying to tell a chicken that hes a cow ;)

Comment: You can change type of frmkeepBooks to base class of both forms e.g. Form.

Comment: Change the type of `frmkeepBooks` to `frmMain`?  Seems like the most obvious approach anyway.

Comment: Thank you david that seems to have fixed it ill need to test it of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first line into:

```
public static frmMain frmkeepBooks = null;
```

The types should be equal (or in herited) and probably it is not.

Comment: @Steve : your comment about constructors was right, I deleted/undeleted and updated the answer but your comment got lost; sorry.

Comment: I'm currently attending University in my first year and for some reason my sixth form didn't cover coding of any kind so this is all new to me, not to mention i wrote this code as it was shown in the lecture slides we were given so any of the names or lack of constructors isn't entirely down to me. Its hard to tell if you have a bad teacher if you don't know any better :L

Comment: I didn't downvote you, also I did not make any personal remarks. Just keep on coding, ask questions here (you get useful comments and answers normally). Have fun programming!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to just show the new form on top of the old as a dialog keeping the old form up?  I don't quite understand why you are trying to set your instance of `frmMain` to equal a null instance of `frmAddBook`.

if you are trying to open new form as a dialog you would do something like this:

```
public static frmAddBook frmkeepBooks;

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frmKeepBooks = new frmAddBook();
    /* if you want to display the 2nd form ontop of the first disallowing 
       user interaction on the first until the 2nd form closes */
     frmKeepBooks.ShowDialog();
     // If you want to allow interaction on either form
     frmKeepBooks.Show();
     /* maybe you don't want to display the first form
        anymore after the 2nd form is displayed */
      this.Visible = false;
}
```

I think this question needs some clarification on what you are trying to do exactly.